# Delete fields in certain columns in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I need to look for duplicate values in each record after column 8 and if any, delete it. First two values in each record can be the same and not to be deleted.

```
with open("User.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        for column in reader:
            print(column)
```

the code above reads the file in the console:

```
['257488', '257488', '3', '1234', '', '1', '1', '', '160000', '', '0', '', '']
['257488', '257488', '3', '1234', '', '1', '1', '', '160000', '', '0', '', '']
['270076', '270076', '2', '1234', '', '1', '1', '', '40000', '270076CASH', '270076CASH', '', '']
['270076', '270076', '2', '1234', '', '1', '1', '', '40000', '270076CASH', '0', '', '']
```

Note: the 2nd value "270076CASH" in row 3 above to be deleted. It should check and delete for the rest of the rows.

Comment: What about the duplicate empty strings in the other records?

Comment: Is it supposed to remove the duplicate element, or replace it with a blank?

Comment: Create a `set`. Loop through the elements starting from `8`. Check if the element is in the set. If it is, delete it, otherwise add it to the set.

Comment: Empty string to be left alone and remove the duplicate elements - thanks

Comment: What problem are you having coding this?

Comment: I'm not having any issue, however not sure what is the best way to code it. I will try your previous set idea. - thanks

Comment: IMO it would be best for you to show the actual lines of the input csv file `User.csv`—not what `print` displays, and the same for the lines of the desired result you want. Please [edit] your question and do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to solve this problem is to take all the items after column 8 and only store the unique items (checked through a standard `for` loop and `if` statement). Afterwards, take these unique items after column 8 and insert them back into the record. Below, is a fairly heavily commented implementation of this:

```
with open( 'User.csv' ) as file:
    reader = csv.reader( file )
    for record in reader:

        # store all items after column 8 into a temporary list
        subset_list = record[9:]

        # keep track of unique (non-duplicate) items in the subset
        unique_subset = []

        # loop through every item of the subset
        for item in subset_list:

            # check if the current item already exists, then append
            if not item in unique_subset or item == '':
                unique_subset.append( item )

        # after looping through subset, reinsert the unique entries into column
        new_record = record[:9] + unique_subset[:]

        # verify operations
        print( new_record )
```

Comment: No problem! Feel free to upvote my answer or mark it if it helped